Assembly code not working; need help finding the issue
I am writing assembly code for my university course and it is not working at all. I have never written code like this before and I'm unsure what I am doing wrong. The code links to a few other codes for different things. Here is the code:
%include "asm_io.inc"

section .data
    name_prompt db "Enter your name: ", 0
    count_prompt db "Enter the number of repetitions (50-100): ", 0
    error_msg db "Error: Number must be between 50 and 100.", 10, 0
    welcome_msg db "Welcome, ", 0
    newline db 10, 0

section .bss
    name resb 128   ; Allocate 128 bytes for the name
    num_reps resd 1

section .text
    global asm_main      ; Declare the function to be used by the C code
    extern print_string  ; External declarations from asm_io.inc
    extern read_char
    extern read_int
    extern print_nl

asm_main:                ; Entry point for the C code
    push ebp             ; Save the base pointer (set up stack frame)
    mov ebp, esp         ; Move stack pointer into base pointer

    ; Prompt for name
    push name_prompt
    call print_string
    add esp, 4            ; Properly clean up the stack after calling print_string

    ; Read the name character-by-character
    lea eax, [name]
    call read_char_loop
    call print_nl

validate_reps:
    ; Prompt for number of repetitions
    push count_prompt
    call print_string
    add esp, 4

    ; Read number of repetitions
    call read_int
    mov [num_reps], eax

    ; Validate repetitions (must be between 50 and 100)
    cmp eax, 50
    jl invalid_reps
    cmp eax, 100
    jg invalid_reps

    ; Print welcome message the number of times specified
    mov ecx, [num_reps]
print_loop:
    cmp ecx, 0
    jle end_loop

    push welcome_msg
    call print_string
    add esp, 4

    lea eax, [name]
    push eax
    call print_string
    add esp, 4

    call print_nl
    dec ecx
    jmp print_loop

invalid_reps:
    push error_msg
    call print_string
    add esp, 4
    call print_nl
    jmp validate_reps

end_loop:
    ; Exit program cleanly using the exit system call
    mov eax, 1           ; SYS_exit
    xor ebx, ebx         ; Status code 0
    int 0x80

read_char_loop:
    lea edi, [name]
    mov ecx, 128

read_next_char:
    call read_char
    cmp al, 10
    je end_read_char
    mov [edi], al
    inc edi
    loop read_next_char

end_read_char:
    mov byte [edi], 0
    ret

After running a debugger I believe the segmentation fault is happening within the print_string function which is related to the manipulation of the stack and memory access.
Also "asm_io.inc" is this code below:
    extern  read_int, print_int, print_string
    extern  read_char, print_char, print_nl
    extern  sub_dump_regs, sub_dump_mem, sub_dump_math, sub_dump_stack

%macro  dump_regs 1
    push      dword %1
    call      sub_dump_regs
%endmacro


;
; usage: dump_mem label, start-address, # paragraphs
%macro  dump_mem 3
    push     dword %1
    push     dword %2
    push     dword %3
    call     sub_dump_mem
%endmacro

%macro  dump_math 1
    push     dword %1
    call     sub_dump_math
%endmacro

%macro  dump_stack 3
    push     dword %3
        push     dword %2
    push     dword %1
        call     sub_dump_stack
%endmacro

I was given that code and also a code called asm_io.asm which has all of the definitions for the functions and also a c code file like the one below:
int __attribute__((cdecl)) asm_main( void );
int main() {
int ret_status;
ret_status = asm_main();
return ret_status;
}

print_string:
    enter   0,0
    pusha
    pushf

    push    eax
    push    dword string_format
    call    _printf
    pop ecx
    pop ecx

    popf
    popa
    leave
    ret


What command line do you use to compile and link this code? What OS are you using?

You pushed the argument to the stack:
push name_prompt
call print_string

whereas print_string is looking for it inside EAX:
push    eax
push    dword string_format ; assuming a "%s" constant for printf
call    _printf

Suggested fix: pass the address of your string in EAX.

Also it seems to me that the function restores the stack after itself, so you should double-check that add esp, 4 is actually needed.
If there is an explanation on how the IO library you are using expects its arguments to be passed, you should look at it again.

fix it now thanks for the help
